# Proguard: How to keep everything except specific condition?

Tags: proguard

I'm using Proguard to obfuscate my code, and I need to keep every third party libraries like:

```
-keep class com.layer.**
-dontwarn com.layer.**
-keep class com.twitter.**
-keep class android.support.**
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
...
```

And whenever I add a new third party library, I need to check its package name and add it to my proguard config file, or the app may crashes.

Can't I write the rule just like this? I don't care about codes that's not mine.

```
-keep class !(my.package.name.**)
-dontwarn !(my.package.name.**)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To keep everything except classes in your own package you can use the rule that you already pointed out (excluding the brackets):

```
-keep class !my.package.name.** { *; }
```

This will implicitly keep everything else.
You still can add additionally **-keep** rules for your classes if needed.

The rule for the **-dontwarn** should work in a similar way:

```
-dontwarn !my.package.name.**,**
```

You can also add similar **-dontnote** rules if needed.

Comment: I tried this but it third party library warnings are still popping up. I only have -keep, -dontwarn, -verbose, and -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Annotation.

Comment: Then you can try using -dontwarn !my.package.name.**,**

Comment: Thanks, the `, **` was necessary for -dontwarn line.

Comment: Does it still work for you? I can't get it running: [Proguard (R8) negate operator not working to keep anything except certain packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248681/proguard-r8-negate-operator-not-working-to-keep-anything-except-certain-packag?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I had to use below syntax to keep class and methods intact `-keep class !my.package.name.**,** { *; }`